# Create multiple polygons from Excel file containing vertice coordinates in rows

Tags: arcgis-pro, polygon-creation

I'm a beginner in GIS.

I am trying to map on ArcGIS Pro the individual areas used by ~400 fishing vessels. I have an Excel file with 1 row per vessel, and in the columns I have the coordinates of the NW, NE, SW and SE boundaries of its fishing area (The image is a simplified version of my data, I have many more columns with more information).
I know there are ways to use polygon vertices coordinates to create 1 polygon, but since I have so many individual fishing areas to define, I need a more efficient method. Is there a way to do this all at once?

[image]

Comment: Please see the answers presented here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351213/create-a-new-grid-layer-from-a-csv-given-the-four-corner-coordinates/351261#351261

Comment: Those examples are cool, but QGIS not ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way to do this is to write a Python script to generate the polygons.

[ArcMap Help: Writing Geometries](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/writing-geometries.htm)

If you're not into scripting, here's a Esri KB with step by step to create lines from a set of xy coordinates and thence to polygon.

[How To: Create a polygon from an XY data table](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000018069)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not familiar at all with Python so I was hoping it wouldn't come to this but it does seem like the right direction.

Comment: Added another link for you.